# What are the light gray numbers to the left of comments?

Tags: support, comments, comment-votes

What are the light gray numbers which sometimes appear to the immediate left of comments?

As pointed to by the red arrow below.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These numbers are the **score** for each comment. Comments can be upvoted by other members of the community, and the total number of upvotes is displayed out to the left-hand side for each comment.

It's kind of like how questions and answers have a score, based on votes, except that comments cannot be downvoted (only upvoted), so these are really just upvote counts.

Votes are *meant* to signify that the comment is interesting and adds something useful to the post, but they also often signify that they are funny and/or that the community agrees with them.

There is some CSS magic in effect that alters the color in which the score value is displayed, depending on its value. For low scores, the value is in gray. As the score gets higher ("hotter"), the color becomes progressively more orange. Highly-upvoted comments also remain visible, even when there are a lot of comments (enough to force the comments to be "collapsed").

[image: sample comment thread, showing a variety of vote counts]

Notice here that the low-scored comments have their scores shown in gray, the medium-scored comments are brownish, and the high-scored comments are orange. Also note how only the comments that have votes are shown; the rest of the comments are collapsed and need to be explicitly expanded by clicking "show **8** more comments".